# Deploying struts2 + hibernate application using google app engine

Tags: hibernate, google-app-engine, struts2

This is quite cumbersome for me now...

I have developed an application using struts2, and hibernate (mysql) and it is working fine with apache tomcat.

Now i want to deploy it on Google App Engine. I reckon that I have to convert my java dynamic web project to google web project. After doing so, when i tested it on google supplied server for eclipse, it is not running. It's showing exceptions with hibernate. First exception that I encountered is **jdbcException: Not able to open connection** . 
I heard that google app engine(GAE) does not support mysql. Is it true? What are the alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

By default, GAE does not use MySQL or any kind of relational database for storing data, If you want to use relational database in your application then you should go for "Google Cloud SQL". By using this you can store your data in relational database on cloud and can access it from GAE based java application.

Both of the services (GAE and Cloud SQL) are freely available but there are some limitations also. Like free versions have limited storage.

For more details, have a look : https://cloud.google.com/products/cloud-sql